# Why TButton.enable does not produce the expected result in this case?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

The following occurs in a FireMonkey (Delphi XE3) application. Look at the following code (it’s just a dummy example, to illustrate the issue):

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    Button4.Enabled:= false; //This should gray-out the button

    // get busy for some time
    for I := 0 to 100000000000 do
    begin

    end;

    Button4.Enabled:= true;
end;
```

I would expected Button4 to get grayed-out before entering into the busy operation represented by the “for” loop. Nonetheless, it doesn’t.

By the end of the OnClick handler execution, the button does not “seem to react” to the Button4.Enabled:= false. Why?

How can I workaround it?

This works just fine in VCL.

Thanks.

Comment: The MainThread is only for UI Tasks and not for long running calculation tasks. This has to be done in a background task. Disable the button on background task start and enable it, when background task is finished

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not reacting because the reaction is only visible when the button repaints itself. That only happens when the next wm_Paint message is processed, but your code isn't processing messages, so the button, and indeed the entire form, remains unchanged for the duration of that loop.

The immediate fix would be to call `Button4.Repaint`, which will allow the button to update its appearance. That doesn't process all messages, though.

A poor fix would be to occasionally call `Application.ProcessMessages` in your loop, but needing to call that is usually a sign you're doing something wrong.

Finally, the best fix would be to move your long-running task into another thread. Disable the button when you start the task, and enable it whenever the task completes.

Comment: Rob, there's no Update method for FMX controls?

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me, @Jason? It looks like there is no such method in Fire Monkey. There's Repaint, though, which works in VCL, too. It's a synonym for Update.

Comment: well, I couldn't find one - an Update method - so was just putting it out there without making a blanket statement in case I was wrong.  FWIW, I tested using Repaint just now and it didn't work for me - whereas the Application.ProcessMessages does, so it may be slightly more complicated for FMX related controls.

Comment: Calling "Button4.Repaint" does not make any difference. This was one of the first things that I tried and I forgot to mention it when I posted the question. Sorry for that. Application.ProcessMessages workarounds the issue, but I don't like it either. I'll give it a try to the multi-threading. Thanks guys.